# NSWindow animated blur & fade using CATransition and CIFilter: not working the first time?

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nswindow, cifilter, catransition

I try to apply a blur + saturation + fade effect on an NSWindow. Basically, when opening a sheet, I want the window behind the modal sheet to become blurred first.

Strangely, I can achieve this, but always at the *second* animation, never the first one. I've tried various combination of `addSubview` & `addAnimation` etc, but always failed so far.

Any idea? Here is my code:

```
self.contentView!.wantsLayer = true
let animation = CATransition()
animation.type = kCATransitionFade
animation.duration = 0.5

self.contentView!.layer?.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "layerAnimation")

let saturationFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
saturationFilter.setDefaults()
saturationFilter.setValue(2, forKey: "inputSaturation")

let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
blurFilter.setDefaults()
blurFilter.setValue(1.5, forKey:"inputRadius")

let coverView = NSView()
coverView.frame = self.contentView!.bounds
coverView.wantsLayer = true
coverView.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = true
coverView.autoresizingMask = [.ViewWidthSizable, .ViewHeightSizable]
coverView.layer!.opaque = false

coverView.layer!.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
coverView.layer!.backgroundFilters = [saturationFilter, blurFilter]

self.contentView!.addSubview(coverView)
```